# How to build a licensing system in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The user will have to enter a licence key. That key will be writeten somewhere so that on the next application launch, the user won't be needed to insert it again. Let's say that the licence will be kept in a .txt file.

In order to make this aproach more secure, my question is: how could I immediatly embbed that resource in the application after the user writes the key so that the file won't be visible in the app folder?

Or maybe, is there any other way to somehow keep the key in the application after the user writes it and on the next executions, the app will still be able to see it?

The "embed it like a resource" and read it from there the next time thing is just my idea, maybe there are other better ones.

Comment: Your app cannot modify itself. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to get rid of the fact that the user will always have his inserted licence available, to see, to manipulate, to share and so on. I want to hide it permanently.

Comment: Most developers use the registry for storing this kinda stuff... If the key doesn't exist, prompt for a license key. If it does, check for validity.

Comment: Yes, I do that. If there is no licence, there is a licence prompt. If the inserted licence is wrong, the app won't start. I want to avoid the many issues that appear when a correct licence is manually edited afterwards. The licence is kept encripted and the decription algorithm can be mislead by additional stuff written by users afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wants can be fulfilled by easily creating a string variable in `My.Settings` but as this is a about licensing,use :

```
 IO.File.WriteAllText(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "\license.abc","license string here")
```

you may even want to encrypt the file,for that :

```
class Encryptor
{
    public static string Key = "license here";

    public static string Encrypt (string decrypted)
    {
        byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        endec.BlockSize = 128;
        endec.KeySize = 256;
        endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateEncryptor(endec.Key);
        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
    }
```

Another bet would be store the license in registry :

```
 Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;  
 key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("key");  
 key.SetValue("key", "licenseKeyHere");  
 key.Close();
```

Your best bet is to let the activation happen online,let it connect to your database over the net and activate.You can go with SQL Server,MySql or other similar products.

And one more thing,as u mentioned in ur qs,u want to embed a file to the app so tht the user can't see it ? Why not, use my 1st/2nd method and finally do this :

```
 File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: Yes, the encription is a good point, but I already do this as I've mentioned in the above comments. But thank you, Zack!

Comment: you can mark the answer as answer if it helped

Comment: re-read the answer....

Comment: Hmm. Nice idea. I'm wondering: my app gets regular online updates, will those registry be affected by the updates or the key will remain in place?

Comment: it'll remain in the place ...

Comment: Then it seems like it's eveything that I've asked for. Thank you once again!

Comment: re-read my answer..it'll help u a bit more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166906/discussion-between-bvg-and-zack-raiyan).